The exception is not intercepted by CircuitBreaker
I have two services, and when sending a request from one to the other, it goes through FeignClient
package org.example.projectservice.client;

import org.example.projectservice.config.FeignClientConfiguration;
import org.example.projectservice.dto.response.CompanyResponse;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

@FeignClient(value = "${service.company.name}",
        path = "${service.company.path}",
        configuration = FeignClientConfiguration.class)
public interface CompanyFeignClient {

    @GetMapping("/{companyId}")
    CompanyResponse getCompanyById(@PathVariable String companyId);
}

There is also this decoder
package org.example.projectservice.config;

import feign.FeignException;
import feign.Response;
import feign.RetryableException;
import feign.codec.ErrorDecoder;
import org.example.projectservice.exception.FeignClientException;
import org.example.projectservice.exception.NotFoundException;

public class MyDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {
    @Override
    public Exception decode(String s, Response response) {
        FeignException exception = FeignException.errorStatus(s, response);
        int status = response.status();
        if (status == 503) {
            return new RetryableException(
                    status,
                    "Service unavailable",
                    response.request().httpMethod(),
                    (Long) null, 
                    response.request()
            );
        }
        String[] responseMessageSplit = exception.getMessage().split("\"message\"");
        String[] exMessageSplit = responseMessageSplit[responseMessageSplit.length - 1].split("\"");
        System.out.println(exMessageSplit.toString());
        String exMessage = exMessageSplit[exMessageSplit.length - 2];
        if (status == 400) {
            return new FeignClientException(exMessage);
        }
        if (status == 404) {
            return new NotFoundException(exMessage);
        }

        return exception;
    }
}

There is also a service that calls this method
package org.example.projectservice.service.impl;

import feign.FeignException;
import feign.RetryableException;
import io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.annotation.CircuitBreaker;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.example.projectservice.client.CompanyFeignClient;
import org.example.projectservice.dto.response.CompanyResponse;
import org.example.projectservice.exception.ServiceUnAvailableException;
import org.example.projectservice.service.CompanyService;
import org.example.projectservice.utill.ExceptionMessages;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService {
    private final CompanyFeignClient companyFeignClient;

    @Override
    @CircuitBreaker(name = "company", fallbackMethod = "fallBackMethodCompanyService")
    public CompanyResponse getCompanyById(String companyId) {
        return companyFeignClient.getCompanyById(companyId);
    }

    public CompanyResponse fallBackMethodCompanyService(String companyId, RetryableException e) {
        System.out.println("From RetryableException");
        throw new ServiceUnAvailableException(String.format(ExceptionMessages.COMPANY_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE_WITH_MESSAGE, e.getMessage()));
    }

    public CompanyResponse fallBackMethodCompanyService(String companyId, Exception e) {
        System.out.println("From Exception");
        throw new ServiceUnAvailableException(String.format(ExceptionMessages.COMPANY_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE_WITH_MESSAGE, e.getMessage()));
    }
    

}

So the question is, why doesn't CircuitBreaker catch this exception? When called, it flies
feign.RetryableException: Service unavailable
2024-09-27T20:07:23.654552662Z  at org.example.projectservice.config.MyDecoder.decode(MyDecoder.java:21) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2024-09-27T20:07:23.654555808Z  at feign.InvocationContext.decodeError(InvocationContext.java:126) ~[feign-core-13.3.jar:na]
2024-09-27T20:07:23.654558383Z 

It is the RetryableException that flies, not the interception. And sometimes the following flies
java.net.UnknownHostException: fc1fce880bb4
2024-09-27T20:25:15.791819608Z  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2024-09-27T20:25:15.791824077Z  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

I tried all variations, maybe someone was faceing with this kind of problem
